# Required Linq for nested foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq, nested-loops

I have a nested foreach loops like below:

```
if (result != null && result.Error != null && result.Error.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var errorItem in result.Error)
    {
        if (errorItem != null && errorItem.ErrorDetails != null && errorItem.ErrorDetails.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var errorDetailsItem in errorItem.ErrorDetails)
            {
                if (errorDetailsItem != null && errorDetailsItem.Tags != null && errorDetailsItem.Tags.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var tagsItem in errorDetailsItem.Tags)
                    {
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> categoryItem in _categories.Value)
                        {
                            if (categoryItem.Value.Contains(tagsItem))
                            {
                                errorDetailsItem.Categories.Add(categoryItem.Key);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert it to Linq but not able to. Can anyone suggest the good approach to do this?

Comment: `I am trying to convert it to Linq ` and why? Where's your attempt at this?

Comment: Typically, I don't allow collection properties on my models to ever be null, which greatly simplifies using the models, just like the use case you have above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you trying to convert it to LINQ but this should work:

```
result.Error.Where(e => e.ErrorDetails != null && e.ErrorDetails.Any())
             .SelectMany(error => error.ErrorDetails.Where(ed => ed.Tags != null && ed.Tags.Any())
             .SelectMany(errorDetail => errorDetail.Tags))
             .SelectMany(tagItem => _categories.Value.Where(c => c.Value.Contains(tagItem))).ToList()
             .ForEach(categoryItem =>
                     errorDetailsItem.Categories.Add(categoryItem.Key);
            );
```